# html container which does not extend width to its content

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and gave up trying to make my table working - would like to ask for some help.

What I need to do is to display a table occupying 100% of screen width (single row, for example), containing 24 columns (cells). Each cell contains a value of random length. Because of each value is too wide, cell is being extended to display the value (fit the length), and total width of the table exceeds 100% of screen width. I need each cell to occupy 1/24 of screen width and hide characters which does not fit cell width. Of course this should work for resizing this table.

Any ideas how to implement this? I tried playing with 
overflow: hidden
but it didn't help much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your code or a fiddle to your question please.

Comment: if you want to truncate te thext, try using this as a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed layout

```
table{
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

and to hide the data which overflows

```
td{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all table cells same width, apply following property to table

```
{table-layout: fixed;}
```

This property is support by almost all browsers. so, you shouldn't worry about it.